# Crontab is not executing the file?

Tags: linux, cron

I created a crontab which runs the file "NEW" at 9:05 in the morning daily. 
Now this file new creates a file "currentdate" which has the current date in it. But I am not able to understand why the file new is not executing and currentdate don't gets created.

crontab I created is-  5 9 * * * /user/project/new

"new" file is as follows and is located at /user/project.

```
#!/bin/bash

date > currentdate
```

Comment: Is NEW executable? Is it in the PATH that cron has available to it (hint: It's not necessarily the path of the user). Is this an entry in crontab, or is it something like a /etc/crontab.d file? In which case, what's that file's name?

Comment: Did you check permissions?  Which users crontab is the cron entry in and what are the permissions on the "new" script?

Comment: the file is probably created in `/`. You better indicate the full path of the output file: `date > /home/you/currentdate`.

Comment: @Jose Martinez  Yes its executable, it is a script. It has all the permissions. And if i manually run the script "new". The file currentdate gets created with current date in it.

Comment: I have also checked the crontab list, with command " crontab -l" . It shows the command but nothing happens time passes by and no file gets craeted.

Comment: Would you be able to add the following line `touch /tmp/somenewfile` to the script and see if that file is present?  I just want to see if the problem is with crontab calling the script or if the problem is with the "date > currentdate".

Comment: @fedorqui Thanks,it worked by adding the full path of the ouput file. date > /home/you/currentdate.  Thankyou Everyone  :)

Comment: Nice :) Just marked as duplicate to another one that had the same problem. In the future, you may want to go through [Debugging crontab](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info)